# Как использовать отдельный php.ini для каждого сайта php-fpm?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Сервер работает в режиме Nginx + PHP-FPM,
У меня все настроено так что 1 пользователь = 1 сайт, как для каждого сайта сделать использование своего php.ini файла?

Comment: Например, для каждого отдельного пользователя запускать свой отдельный экземпляр php-fpm с опциями `-n` (отключает чтение стандартного php.ini) и `-c путь/к/своему/php.ini` ну и заодно `--fpm-config путь/к/своему/php-fpm.conf`

Comment: А не подскажите как именно запускать для каждого юзера свой php-fpm?